# Sending webhooks from Azure webjob

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-webjobs, webhooks

Having some issues with ASP.net Webhooks and azure webjob.
I try to create a store in both Azure Storage and in a SQL db but the method throws an exception every time.

```
    //// Set up default WebHook logger
    ILogger logger = new TraceLogger();

    //// Set the WebHook Store we want to get WebHook subscriptions from. Azure store requires
    //// a valid Azure Storage connection string named MS_AzureStoreConnectionString.
   // IWebHookStore store = AzureWebHookStore.CreateStore(logger);

    IWebHookStore store = SqlWebHookStore.CreateStore(logger);
```

I get the following error on the CreateStore method.

> Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.IApplicationEnvironment' from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.IApplicationEnvironment' from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

If I create a store in the memory everything works perfect.

```
  _whStore = new MemoryWebHookStore();
  _whManager = new WebHookManager(_whStore, sender, logger);
```

When using a mvc project and running the code in a controller I don´t get any exceptions when creating the sql or storage store...

Appreciate any help to get this sorted.

Regards,
Jonas

Comment: you mean that when you deploy in azure you get this error and when you run locally it works fine. right? during packaging for the deployment does the missing dll mentioned gets copied properly. did you check if it "copy local" property true ?

Comment: Nope. Get this error locally as soon as the debugger hits the create store method.
Copy Local = true.

Comment: Noticed that a reference for System.IO was missing in project references, removed it and it started to work. Very odd.